Can I ask GCC to give me a warning or error on empty structs?
I just had the worst problem ever in my mixed C/C++ project.
The C code is the production code, the C++ is the testing environment. We are compiling with MinGW GCC, but developing on Qt Creator which has clang as an inline pre-compiler.
In my production code, a data structure that I have been using had its last member become obsolete. I therefore removed it and it became empty. However there is a slew of methods that handle this data structure so I did not want to remove the data structure altogether. Development is ongoing and we might later want to add an element in that data structure after all.
After that my program started crashing badly. I realized that methods were passed a certain value but "saw" a different one from their scope. A pointer was pointing to an address that was one byte off from where it should be. Chaos was omnipresent, as well as a thick cloud of mystery.
Then I saw it. Clang had issued an inline warning about how data structures had size zero in C but size one in C++. I had seen it, but ignored it, thinking "who cares". Or more accurately, not thinking. But then I came back to it. I tried putting a dummy into the data structure and tadam ! everything was fixed.
The strange thing is, GCC gives no warning on this. It tries to live through it. However I also discovered that empty structs are actually forbidden in C.
So the question is : can I ask GCC to give me an error on empty structs ? I will make it the default compiler behavior in our project. However I can find no such -Werror flag in the GNU man page.

-pedantic or -Wpedantic will warn about all uses of non-ISO GNU extensions, including this one, but maybe there is a more specific option.

Your problem seems to be not about the struct being empty but of it being unexpected size. If your code depends on the struct to be of a specific size, you should add compile time static assertions checking it.

@EugeneSh.: It sounds to me like the code probably doesn't care what size the struct is, but it does need it to be the same size throughout the program.  Either 0 or 1 would be okay, but what's bad is that the C code treated it as 0 and the C++ code treated it as 1.

Using a dummy member is simplest.  Making sure your code fails to compile when there are any warnings ensures you don't ignore such error messages (-Werror).  It looks as though there isn't a specific GCC warning for an empty structure type. Clang has the -Wgnu-empty-struct warning

If gcc cared to be a quality product for the purpose of C programming, they would have the compiler default to the C language. But they don't, so it defaults to the GNU language. And if you are trying to compile C code with a GNU compiler, you will get bugs. A significant portion of all gcc-related questions on this site is related to bugs caused by the non-conforming GNU mode.

This is teaching me so much about GCC. The C code is production code with fairly or very high expectations on its realiability. It will ultimately be compiled with other compilers. Of course we use static and dynamic analyzers down the line, but still, better to catch issues early. I had no idea GCC was doing things like this compared to the C standard. Any way to tell GCC to stick more closely to the C standard as a default ? Now I can only imagine that this would improve  reliability down the line or in production, on top of any -Werror flags.

@EugeneSh. I have no explicit requirement on the size of this data structure, nor even on it being interpreted to be the exact same size everywhere - nor anything. I just declare it & use it with some getters and setters and that's it. I have no idea how the C and C++ parts interact to cause such a wreckage. But they do, and it seems to be because of that 0 bytes/1 byte interpretation difference.

@NateEldredge see comment above. Also pedantic is too strong I think, also it would initially wreak more havoc than it would help to mitigate (but someone should definitely take the time to try it out and see what happens)

" Any way to tell GCC to stick more closely to the C standard as a default ?" Yes, that's exactly what -pedantic is for. If your code actually is standard C then there should be no havoc. If it isn't, well, it sounds like you want it to be, so you'll know what to fix.
